# Splice value from an array and push spliced value into another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, push, splice

Hello and here is my problem.I have a task,i need to remove elements from an array and push them into another array and then return the array with removed elements. For example, in this case i have to remove all 0 values, and push them into 'a' array and then return 'a' array with there 0 values. I removed 0 values from the array by using splice method and loop, but i don't realy know how to push removed elemts into 'a' array, i've tried to use push method but i does not work for me. Hope you'll help me.Thank you everyone.

```js
function moveZeros(array) {
  var a = [];
  for (var i = array.length - 1; i--;) {
    if (array[i] == "0") {
      array.splice(i, 1);
    }

  }
  
  return a;
}

moveZeros([1, 2, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 3, 0, 1]);
```

Comment: please add the wanted result. do you like to get all zeroes back and `array` has no zeros?

Comment: According to OP `i don't realy know how to push removed elemts into 'a' array`.

Comment: I wanna remove all zeroes from an array an push them into a new array and return the new array.

Answer (score 2):

Using `push` should work. The `.splice` method will return an array with the removed elements, and you can use the spread operator `...` to pass it as a set of arguments to `push`:

```js
function moveZeros(array) {
  var a = [];
  for (var i = array.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (array[i] == "0") {
      a.push(...array.splice(i, 1));
    }

  }
  
  return a;
}
  
const array = [0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 3, 0, 1, 0, 0];
console.log(moveZeros(array));
console.log(array)
```

Finally, you should put the `i--` as the final part of the loop so that it only executes when each iteration finishes (instead of as they begin). Then, change your condition to be `i >= 0` so that you don't miss a zero at the front of the array.

Answer (score 2):

`Array.splice()` returns an array of removed elements, and you can use `Array.concat()` to add them to the `a` array.

**Notes:**

1. Init `i` to `array.length` without the -1, since the condition `i--`
   is checked before the execution of the loop's body.
2. Since the the array is iterated from end to starts, concat `a` to the removed
   elements to maintain the original order.

```js
function moveZeros(array) {
  var a = [];
  for (var i = array.length; i--;) {
    if (array[i] === 0) {
      a = array.splice(i, 1).concat(a);
    }

  }
  
  return a;
}

var result = moveZeros([1, 2, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 3, 0, 1, 0]); // I've added a last 0 to the array to show that all items were removed
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could iterate from the end and splice the array if necessary. This solution mutates the `array`.

```js
function moveZeros(array) {
    var i = array.length,
        a = [];

    while (i--) {
        if (array[i] === 0) {
            a.push(array.splice(i, 1)[0]);
        }
    }
    return a;
}

var array = [1, 2, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 3, 0, 1];

console.log(moveZeros(array));
console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```